# "Only in Russia" or "Only in Moscow" attractions in Moscow

Tags: russia, sightseeing, moscow

For our upcoming trip, I'd like to plan some less-known places, like "only in Russia" or "only in Moscow" style, besides the trivial places like Kremlin, MGU or Tretyakovka.

Maybe riding a bear or firing Kalashnikov, something to impress my 14-18yo kids, stuff that one can't find on Instagram.

Please recommend.

Answer (score 1):

Also, Taganka bunker:

http://bunker42.com/eng/opisanie-ekskursiy.php?ELEMENT_ID=414

It's a real declassified cold-war bunker in central Moscow, with guided tours and rent options for events. I've been there and it's pretty atmospheric.

Comment: Wow, this is really something to see, do they allow taking pictures inside?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure, I think you could take pictures, with the exception of the war room. It's best to ask them directly.

Comment: @alamar the important part is not to fight in the War Room!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider Kubinka tank museum:

https://patriotp.ru/

It's well outside Moscow and I'm not sure they'll let you fire an AKM, but there should be an awful lot of military vehicles and stuff like that.